# AWS Lambda throttling -- why so discouraged?

Tags: aws-lambda

I often throttle Lambda functions when performing things like schema updates on databases, debugging, during certain releases etc. The popup when I click "throttle" though says "Please only use this in case of emergencies". Why is it so strongly discouraged? What negative consequences are there to throttling a function? Why have it at all?